# Effectively using HTML5 data attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, erb

I have this form which should represent a faceted search:

```
<form action="<%= foobar_path %>">
  <div class="container-data">
    <span class="search_all" data-facet="all">Tutto</span>
    <span class="search_author" data-facet="author">Autore</span>
    <span class="search_category" data-facet="category">Categoria</span>
    <span class="search_isbn" data-facet="isbn">ISBN</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Invia" class="search_submit">
</form>
```

How do I fetch the data-facet value in RubyOnRails *using Ruby*? Isn't it supposed to be inside a params' **data** hash?

Seems a pretty legit use of data attributes, but if I'm missing something obvious... I'm here to learn :) Alternative ways to accomplish the same task are also appreciated.

TIA

Comment: For "fetch the data-facet value in RubyOnRails" you need use some client logic implement on javascript. Ruby live in your server and cant fetch data from client like you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to "fetch the data attributes" on the server side in Ruby/Rails. You **set** these values in Rails.

Why?

Think of a separation of concerns (bear with me, this is a very high level abstraction):

- Rails "just" delivers the HTML and Javascript files
- the HTML defines the structure of the things you'd like to present
- the Javascript defines the behavior of the different things
- with data attributes you get an *easy and standardized* way to parameterize the behavior without hard coding value into your Javascript

Since you are in control when generating the HTML code (i.e. generating data attributes) you could just write generic Javascripts and leverage the parameterization to the data attributes.

---

In your form example, you would still use basic input fields, like so:

```ruby
<%= form_tag url: foobar_path do %>
  <div class="container-data">
    <%= text_field_tag :all, placeholder: 'Tutto' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :author,   data: { facet: 'autocomplete', url: authors_path(format: :json) }, placeholder: 'Autore' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :category, data: { facet: 'autocomplete', url: categories_path(format: :json) }, placeholder: 'Categoria' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :isbn,     data: { facet: 'isbn' }, placeholder: 'ISBN' %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag 'Invia', class: 'search_submit' %>
<% end %>
```

and use could use the `data-facet` attribute to initialize some kind of additional behaviour, like autocompletion or format validation (I'd admit this is a constructed example):

```js
$(document)
.on('change keyup', '[data-facet="isbn"]', function(event){
  var value = $(this).val() // e.g. validate 
})
.on('change keyup', '[data-facet="autocomplete"]', function(event){
  var value = $(this).val(),
      url = $(this).data('url') // use `url` to fetch auto completion suggestions
})
```